# Ansible through docker, docker host in the inventory

Tags: docker, ansible

Using [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/williamyeh/ansible/) from Docker Hub, I'm trying to run an ansible playbook that would configure the machine on which the container is running.

As an example, I run this:

```
docker run --net="host" -v <path_inventory>:/inventory -v <path_playbook>:/playbook.yml williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu16.04 ansible-playbook -vvvv -i /inventory /playbook.yml
```

With this options, I can ping localhost and the inventory and playbook are both accessible.

The inventory is configured to use a local connection:

```
[executors]
127.0.0.1

[executors:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_user=<my_user_in_docker_host>
ansible_become=True
```

The group *executors* is the one referenced from the playbook.

I see that the playbook is trying to connect as root (what I get by default when I attach to the container). Specifying *-u* when running the container doesn't seem to get along with Ansible.

> <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root

... followed by errors complaining about any command not available, after a successful local connection. That is what makes no sense for me given that both root or non-root users can execute them.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

this image is designed to serve as a base for other images, and to take advantadge of ansible as a way of provisioning the requirements of the image rather than using the Dockerfile only.

This is stated in the documentation of the docker image:

> Used mostly as a base image for configuring other software stack on
>   some specified Linux distribution(s).

Think of it as a base image to perform CI tasks on a lighter way than using other options (VMs, Vagrant...)

Take in account that the good thing about docker is that it isolates the host from the containers, so you can not reach the host files from the containers (except for whatever volumes you bind). Otherwise, it would be a security problem. [See Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/)

regards

Comment: Thanks for the reference: my use case is a bit different and the documentation helps clarifying it. I understand that a docker container is not meant to modify files on a host machine, but I would consider a good practice to use docker to isolate an app, even if it's meant to configure another host. In my case, I will SSH localhost, given that a volume is not enough to execute those commands in the playbook. This seems like a good practice/compromise to me. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use ansible to configure the host from within a docker container. However, I didn't use a docker host network, but a docker bridge network.

When you start an ansible playbook in a container, then localhost will be the localhost of the container itself. This is just fine, because local_action(s) in ansible run in the container itself and remote actions on the host.

This is the modified version of your docker run example:

```
docker run -v <path_inventory>:/inventory -v <path_playbook>:/playbook.yml williamyeh/ansible:ubuntu16.04 ansible-playbook -vvvv -i /inventory/playbook.yml
```

You should't configure the inventory to use localhost or a local connection, but to use the host (machine) and connect via ssh. This is an example:

```
[executors]
<my_host_ip>

[executors:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=<my_host_user>
ansible_become=True
```

Assuming your docker container is running in the default bridge, you can find my_host_ip with the following command:

```
ip addr show docker0
```

The container will connect with ssh to the docker interface on the host.

Some additional hints:

- ssh needs to listen on the docker0 interface
- iptables/nftables needs to provide ssh access from the ansible container to the docker0 interface
- Ansible uses keys to connect via ssh by default. By using the -k and/or the -K parameters of the ansible-playbook command, you can provide a password instead.